# ArrayList iteration confusion

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an issue with my arraylist.

I have an arraylist with shoes. These shoes can be have categories and prices: that is smart shoes, casual shoes and so on, but I want to get the total amount of shoes per category.

For example, if my arraylist has 10 smart shoes each with its own price and 15 casual shoes with their prices respectively, I want to get only the category and how much each total that category has.

I have an arraylist called category that stores a category and the total amount of of shoes that category has and a receipt arraylist that has the price, shoe, and category.

```
float total = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < receipts.size(); i++){

    for(int j = 0; j< receipts.size(); j++)
        if (TextUtils.equals(receipts.get(i).getCategory(), receipts.get(j).getCategory()))
            total += Float.parseFloat(receipts.get(j).getPrice());

    categories.add(new Category(receipts.get(i).getCategory(),String.valueOf(total)));
    total = 0;
}
```

The issue with this code is I tend to get multiple values of one category.

Comment: no, its something to do with stackoverflow, let me work on it.

Comment: You have to check if a category is already added. With your current code, when you iterate a list containing `['Casual', 'Casual']`, you will get two casual categories, each holding a total value of 2.

Comment: Have you considered using a `Map` to ensure that you only keep one of each category?

Comment: No idea what the type of `getCategory()` is, but I'd be inclined to sort the receipts by category, so that the equal categories are together; then just do a pass through the list.

Comment: @twentylemon would you please be of help? am stuck here.

Comment: @Mr.Yetti checking is giving me the `concurrentmofication` exception

Comment: @AndyTurner what do you mean?

Comment: @Chrometobia sort the list so that the receipts for category A are together, the receipts for category B are together etc. Then it's easy just to find the blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use java 8, I recommend use lambda. For example, if you have an array of Shoe, you can separate the shoes by category:

```
ArrayList<Shoe> receipts = new ArrayList<>();

final Map<Long, List<Shoe>> collect = receipts.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Shoe::getIdCategory));
```

Then you can get the collection of you preference:

```
final List<Shoe> xShoes = collect.get(1);
final List<Shoe> yShoes = collect.get(2);
```

And also you can get the total price with:

```
long priceX = xShoes.stream().map(Shoe::getPrice).reduce((aLong, aLong2) -> aLong + aLong2).get();
    long priceY = xShoes.stream().map(Shoe::getPrice).reduce((aLong, aLong2) -> aLong + aLong2).get();
```

Comment: thank you very much, had a lot of trouble making this work.

Comment: You could also try: ```Map<String, Long> map = receipts.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Shoe::getCategory, Collectors.counting()));``` for direct map of shoe category to count.

Comment: If my answer is correct. Can you accept the answer? :)

Comment: oooh sorry, i forgot.